# How do Unix systems keep track of shared memory when processes fork()?

Tags: unix, memory-management, fork, shared-memory, virtual-memory

*Process A* creates a shared memory region and shares it with *Process B*. Then *Process A* forks and thereby creates *Process C*. By definition, *C* now has access to the same shared memory regions. If *A* dies, *C* and *B* still have access to the memory region. Only when *C* and *B* also die, the physical memory is free'd again.

How do Unix systems achieve this? Do they store information about which memory is shared with whom per-process or is this information global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared memory region has a reference counter. It gets incremented whenever a process opens the shared memory or gets it by being forked from a process that had it open. It gets decremented when a process closes the shared memory or exits. When the counter goes to 0, the shared memory region is discarded.

Comment: Thank you, but, is this information stored *on the process* or is the information about existing shared memory areas global?

Comment: It's global, since there's one counter for each shared memory region. How could it be in the process?

Comment: It could be. In my kernel project (http://ghostkernel.org/), I'm reworking my shared memory implementation so I can implement forking. In my current implementation, the creating process is the "physical owner" to the region it wants to share. Processes that the area is shared with don't have this flag. Therefore the memory is free'd once the physical owner of the shared memory dies. But, as you can see this won't work out with fork, because the physical owner could die, but the physical pages would still have to stay.

Comment: If the information about shared memory is global, what happens if the physical memory behind the shared region is not contiguous? Does the system store the address for *each* physical page that a shared region has?

Comment: It's for each page. It's part of the page table used by the virtual memory system.

Comment: "For each page" - for each *physical page*? Where did you find that information? How is this even possible with reasonable performance/memory overhead?

Comment: Almost everything about virtual memory is managed in the page table.

Comment: No. In x86, page directories & tables only have 3 bits per entry that could be used for such purposes.

Comment: I'm talking about the operating system, not hardware. How could something that's a count of processes be in per-process information -- it's an inherently cross-process piece of data, so it has to be global.

Comment: The exact details will differ based on the OS. Another way to do it is with a linked list pointing to per-process VM information for the page. When the list becomes empty, the shared memory can be discarded.